# How to return 'own' 404 custom page?

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

In case if error occurred on my web site I do the following:

```
        Server.Transfer("/error.aspx");
```

and that page has code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```

If I work on the localhost then together with 404 status returned for the page, page displays 'proper error description'.

Once I published the same code to the internet all pages with errors are still displayed with 404 status code, but the don't have the content. Instead, they have the standard 404 error message:

> 404 - File or directory not found.

if the line "Response.StatusCode = 404" commented out then the proper page is provided, but it has 200 status code.

**Question:** how to return user-friendly error page that in the same time has 404 error status code?

Any thoughts are welcome! Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: I've always done custom 404 pages in the same way. 1) Transfer to error page 2) user friendly page copy and a 404 under the bonnet for robots.
One site I'm trying to do this on now I'm having exactly the same problem - if I add "Response.Status" then a standard 404 is displayed - remove the response.status and the page copy appears but returns a 200. 
My uneducated guess is something changed in .NET4 framework...

Answer (score 19):

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/GenericErrorPage.aspx">

     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/404.aspx" />

</customErrors>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx

Comment: While it's totally correct, I'd recommend, if possible, not to use an ASPX for error pages. If the error is related to something in the ASP engine then the error page may not load as well..

Comment: I agree @justabuzz, we actually had an application where this used to happen - "Furthermore, ASP .NET encountered an error while trying to display the custom error page for the exception"

Comment: I think an aspx page for a 404 is ok 'cos if it errors it's likely to display the 500 page instead. But if that's an aspx page...

Comment: doesn't work for xxx.xom/wrongfolder, i get `404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Answer (score 17):

A ha!

Try this:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

I found as soon as I added `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors=true` before setting the status code, I would see the normal page copy AND a 404 is returned. Without this line the standard IIS 404 page is displayed.

Alternatively, this can be set in the web.config like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough">
        // custom error page mappings
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

The key thing here is `existingResponse="PassThrough"`

This was added to IIS7 thus is required on sites running in Integrated Pipeline mode.

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx

**Update**
Updating for clarrification/more info as people are still finding this useful. 
It's worth noting that if you need a simple, generic 404 page use the web.config method (and best make it a plain HTML page).

The method I describe works best if you have a heavily dynamic or CMS driven site where any given page could potentially return a 404 but you want to show your visitor related info.

For example, a special offers page (offers/some-offer) could do a lookup for the offer (some-offer) and if it doesn't exist show alternative or related offers while returning a 404 under the bonnet. As far as the visitor is aware they've just been told the offer is no longer available but they're still in the offers section but we're also telling robots to un-index the URL.
This would be a lot harder to do if there was just one generic 404 page.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer almost 10 years later haha

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by configuring your web.config file. Please check the link below to an article, which explains at the bottom of the page, how to display different custom error pages for different HTTP error statuses.

- [Displaying a Custom Error Page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)

Answer (score 5):

To show your **own page** with the **correct 404** statuscode, you can use the following code:

1) In your web.config add the following:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

and:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="404.htm" responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
```

2) Add a 404.htm file to the **root** of your website:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>404 - Not Found</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=/404-PAGE" />
  </head>
  <body>
       CONTENT
  </body>
</html>
```

You can either add content to the body of this file and remove the META refresh or simply use the META refresh to open a page within your CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Combining Jag's and adt's answers, I still had a problem. When a 404 was handled by the static file handler (as opposed to ASP.NET), I got a blank response. (The status was correctly 404.)

To fix it, I had to add `errorMode="Custom"` to the `<httpErrors>` element. If your error page uses ASP.NET, you need to include `responseMode="ExecuteURL"`.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
     <remove statusCode="404"/>
     <error statusCode="404" path="ErrorPages/error404.htm" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  </httpErrors>
```

This works for me if I don't use the tilde `(~)` in the path attribute

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering in ASPNET 6.0+ you can now use the following official solution [1]

In Program.cs:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCode", "?statusCode={0}");
```

In StatusCode.cshtml.cs

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class StatusCodeModel : PageModel
{
    public int OriginalStatusCode { get; set; }

    public string? OriginalPathAndQuery { get; set; }

    [ViewData]
    public string Code { get; set; } = "";

    public void OnGet(int statusCode)
    {
        OriginalStatusCode = statusCode;
        Code = statusCode.ToString();
        var statusCodeReExecuteFeature =
            HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

        if (statusCodeReExecuteFeature is not null)
        {
            OriginalPathAndQuery = string.Join(
                statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalPathBase,
                statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalPath,
                statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalQueryString);
        }
    }
}
```

In StatusCode.cshtml  (here is where you can customize to your sites theme)

```
@page
@model StatusCodeModel


Its a Custom Page for Status Code: @ViewData["Code"]
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#usestatuscodepageswithreexecute

Answer (score -1):

To create & access 404 page in asp.net C# follow the steps:

1)create an 404.html file & add your content

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
      body {
  color: #797979;
  background: #eaeaea;
  font-family: 'Ruda', sans-serif;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}
      .p404 img {
  margin-top: 120px;
}
      .centered {
  text-align: center;
}
      .p404 h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 p404 centered">
              <img src="assets/img/404.png" alt="">
              <h1>DON'T PANIC!!</h1>
              <h3>The page you are looking for doesn't exist.</h3>
              <br>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                      <a class="btn btn-success" href="Default.aspx">Back To Home</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
           
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. in web config add this code

```
   <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.html" />
    </customErrors>   
  </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```