# how to remove version information from server error "the resource cannot be found"

Tags: asp.net, .net, internal-server-error

While browsing a page, I am getting the error :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /WebResource.axd
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.33

The error is as expected and what i need is a way to hide/remove the **version information**.!? if there is any...

Comment: Make your own 404 page then you can have it include whatever you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116804/how-to-return-own-404-custom-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom page which you want your users to see and then in the `web.config` file have something like

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="404.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
 ...
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

There are 3 different mode `On`, `Off`, `RemoteOnly`

**On** - Specifies that custom errors are enabled. If no defaultRedirect attribute is specified, users see a generic error. The custom errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.

**Off** - Specifies that custom errors are disabled. The detailed ASP.NET errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.

**RemoteOnly** - Specifies that custom errors are shown only to the remote clients, and that ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host. This is the default value.

The default is `RemoteOnly` further reading **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**. Also you might want to look at this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404091/3793448)** if you want to know the difference between `customErrors` and `httpErrors`